# Event bus versus Local broadcast Manager: which one is best

Tags: android, event-bus

My app is heavily depended on Local broadcast ,for every activity invocation am invoking the broadcast registration method so is it good to move to any event bus.

Two primary concerns of using Local broadcast Manager.

1. Every activity require the registration
2. Registration method execution time(Around 10 actions are registered)

I think the event bus will improve overall execution and performance of my app.

Comment: Can someone please confirm it

Comment: Using Eventbus will give you more freedom than LocalBroadcast , ie you could send complex data object via event bus without using serialization. And also eventbus is easy to use.

Answer (score 9):

Most event bus libraries provide reflection-based registration which is less efficient than LocalBroadcastManager. The main reason for using the event bus would be coding ease.

Comment: That is not true: `Because of a build time indexing of annotations, EventBus does not need to do annotation reflection during your app’s run time.` from [here](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/)

Comment: You may be talking about EventBus 3 specifically, while I wrote MOST.

Comment: BTW the mentioned feature (http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/subscriber-index/) is an optional optimization that requires a special Gradle plugin and additional boilerplate code, which may not be appropriate in some projects.

Answer (score 7):

afaik, there are some benefits using event-bus instead of LocalBroadcastManager:

1. **Code decoupling.**
   By decoupling your code, you will minimize your class which formerly using LocalBroadcastManager. Simpler code less error and improve code readability.
2. **Ease of Maintenance.**
   This somewhat related to no.1, decoupled code make it easy to maintained.
3. **Localizing error.**
4. **Avoids complex and error-prone dependencies and life cycle issues.**
5. **Avoid further bugs.**

Answer (score 5):

[EventBus FAQ](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/faq/)

> **How is EventBus different to Android’s BroadcastReceiver/Intent system?**
>
> Unlike Android’s BroadcastReceiver/Intent system, EventBus uses
>   standard Java classes as events and offers a more convenient API.
>   EventBus is intended for a lot more uses cases where you wouldn’t want
>   to go through the hassle of setting up Intents, preparing Intent
>   extras, implementing broadcast receivers, and extracting Intent extras
>   again. Also, EventBus comes with a much lower overhead.